# How ot install Hoop in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, installation

I try to install Hoop in ubuntu desktop 12.04. I have already install hadoop-1.0.2. My installation is following http://cloudera.github.com/hoop/docs/latest/ServerSetup.html
I installed maven 3.0.4, git the hoop. However, the problem come when I did,

```
hoop $ mvn clean package site assembly:single
```

the problem is:

```
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /home/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.4/jersey-project-1.4.pom: end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...</center>\r\n</body>... @6:8)  @ /home/pc/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.4/jersey-project-1.4.pom, line 6, column 8
```

and

```
[ERROR] /home/pc/hoop/hoop-server/src/main/java/com/cloudera/hoop/Hoop.java:[222,23] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class Hoop

[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:   [unknown-version], must be "pom" but is "jar" @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ line 44, column 99
[ERROR] 'version' is missing. @ line 44, column 99


[INFO] Hoop Project POM .................................. SUCCESS [7.774s]
[INFO] Hoop TestNG ....................................... SUCCESS [12:16.761s]
[INFO] Hoop Server ....................................... FAILURE [1.161s]
[INFO] Hoop WebApp ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hoop Client ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hoop Docs ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hoop Distro ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hoop Main ......................................... SKIPPED
```

what should I do?

I change the maven to maven2, and I did

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/packager
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/jersey
```

as Daniel Baktiar said. But there is new problem now

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   Hoop Project POM
[INFO]   Hoop TestNG
[INFO]   Hoop Server
[INFO]   Hoop WebApp
[INFO]   Hoop Client
[INFO]   Hoop Docs
[INFO]   Hoop Distro
[INFO]   Hoop Main
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hoop Project POM
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, package, site, assembly:single]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [enforcer:enforce {execution: clean}]
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with     message:
Detected Maven Version: 2.2.1 is not in the allowed range [3.0.0,).
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 01 15:51:06 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/141M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what should I do now?

Comment: What does your `jersey-project-1.4.pom` file look like?

Comment: <html>^M                                                                                                                                                                    
  2 <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>^M
  3 <body bgcolor="white">^M
  4 <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>^M
  5 <hr><center>nginx/0.6.39</center>^M
  6 </body>^M
  7 </html>^M

Comment: I didn't edit it, is this the Maven configuration?

Comment: I know what's the problem. Look at my answer.

Comment: The maven I installed is 3.0.4. Maybe that is a problem.

Comment: CrazyBone, you are unfair. You said that Maven 3.0.4 was installed in your initial question? But you then said by installing it, it solved the problem. I down vote you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven2.0 doesn't work in hoop installation. About the problem in maven3.0.4, you can try to update pom.xml with official file. just search jersey-project-1.4.pom in google.

Answer (score 0):

Your local Maven 2 repository was messed up due to intermittent disruption in the proxy (nginx). Because the file is not a valid .pom file, the Maven 2 cannot proceed.

What you should do is to remove the it first.

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/packager
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/jersey
```

After that, run the Maven mvn command again.

Comment: it will generate the .pom file. and still the problem.